# Can't delete files on an external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, delete

I have an external HD connected to my computer and I can't delete any files from it. When I right click a file or folder, the "move to trash" option doesn't appear and when I try to move it to trash, it says it can't and that it will completely delete it. When I confirm it, I get an error saying this:

```
You do not have sufficient permissions to remove "x"
Error removing file /media/user/HardDrive/file/: Read-only file system
```

I tried using

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw 'HardDrive'
```

When I did, it appeared as if it has worked, but when I delete a folder, it says

```
Deleted x files
[enter increasing number here]/[number of actual files in the folder]
```

And when I cancel the action, the folder disappears, but when I go to another directory and then back to the one I tried to delete, it's there again. Same with, for example, text files

I also tried

```
sudo chmod ugo+wx 'HardDrive'
```

But it doesn't do anything

Comment: Was `HardDrive` last mounted on a Windows system?

Comment: Like, it was used before on a windows system? Yes, it was

Comment: Take the HD back to Windows, turn OFF the Windows "Fast Boot" option, then unmount the HD.

Comment: Uh, I didn't really get that, do you mind explaining again? Sorry, I'm still a noob to all of this

Comment: "Turn off Windows Fast Boot" is an internet searchable string of words  AND is a Windows setting, and inappropriate for AskUbuntu.

Comment: I’d suggest copy any files you need from that drive, then reformat it. As the other comments say, if it’s left in an  unsafe state by Windows, Ubuntu won’t mount it read-write, so you won’t be able to delete anything. There may be  other explanations, but reformatting should get the drive working again as you want.